# For a pair of non-commutative ring $(R, S)$, is there a faithfully semidualizing $(R, S)$-bimodule?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, tilting

Given a pair of non-commutative rings $(R, S)$, how to construct a faithfully semidualizing $(R, S)$-bimodule?

Henrik Holm and Diana White introduced the concept of faithfully semidualizing bimodules in the paper named "Foxby equivalence over associative rings".

Semidualizing modules provide
a generalization of a free
module of rank one, that is, any ring $R$ with a unit is a semidualizing module. Semidualizing modules are also called generalized tilting modules (see Wakamatsu, [Tilting modules and Auslander's Gorenstein property](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869304000201), Corollary 3.2). These modules share some of the basic properties with their subclass
consisting of all tilting modules. It is still an open problem - known as the Wakamatsu
Tilting Conjecture - whether any Wakamatsu tilting module of finite projective
dimension is tilting. Since faithfully semidualizing bimodules have more nice properties, we hope to find more examples.

For more details, see Holm, White,
[Foxby equivalence over associative rings](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250692289).

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer to your question if you provide a little more background.  What is a semidualizing bimodule?  What does the paper say?

Comment: semidualizing bimodules are also called Wakamatsu tilting modules or generalized tilting modules.